# Pokemon GO Startup Problems

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm having trouble getting Pokemon GO to run on my phone, it's stuck on a loading screen that has the "Pokemon GO" logo at the top, a cancel button ("X") at the bottom and a spinny ball in the middle and never starts the game. I've played it many times on this phone (to level 36) so not sure what's going on. I've tried looking for information on line about it but there's nothing I can see that's similar.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was having login problems recently too.  It seems one of their data migrations was bugged in a recent upgrade.  I was able to fix the problem by clearing my local cache and logging in again (Settings > Apps > Pokemon GO > Storage > Clear Data, Android only).

If you are on iOS, you have less control over how your apps are managed and you'll have to uninstall and reinstall the game again.  Your Pokémon are saved server-side though, so you will still have everything after you log in again.